# Fitrado de un objeto con una relación nested con django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, djangorestframework

necesito su ayuda.
Estoy utilizando Django 2.2 y Django rest framework y el ejemplo abajo es un queryset que necesito filtrar por idCategoria y idSubcategoria, he intentado usar el `queryset.filter(Campo= Parametro)`, pero no funciona. Como uds se dan cuenta el campo **idCategoria** y **idSubcategoria**, estan andidado al campo **idProfesion**

```
{
        "idProfesionProfesional": 2,
        "idProfesion": {
            "idProfesion": 1,
            "Nombre": "Informatica",
            "srcIcono": "computer",
            "Tipo": "PR",
            "idSubcategoria": 1,
            "idCategoria": 1
        },
        "idProfesional": {
            "idProfesional": 2,
            "idPersona": {
                "idPersona": 18,
                "Nombre": "Erick"
                "Apaterno": "Aguilar",
                "Amaterno": "Perez",
               "email": "ejemplo@gmail.com",
            }
        }
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar a como realizar el filtrado y que el servidor solo me devuelva el resultado si la**idCategoria** y la **idSubcategoria** coincide con la petición solicitada.
Gracias.

El modelo para el **idProfesion**:

```
class Profesiones(models.Model):
    """Model definition for Profesiones."""

    #DEFINICION ENUM TYPE
    PROFESIONAL = 'PR'
    ARTESANO = 'AR'
    TIPO_PROFESIONAL = [
        (PROFESIONAL,'PROFESIONAL'),
        (ARTESANO,'ARTESANO'),
    ]
    #ATRIBUTOS 
    idProfesion = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 70, blank = False, null = False)
    idSubcategoria = models.ForeignKey('Subcategorias', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    idCategoria = models.ForeignKey('Categorias', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    srcIcono = models.CharField(max_length = 25, blank = False, null = False)
    Tipo = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = TIPO_PROFESIONAL, default = PROFESIONAL)
```

El modelo para **idProfesional**

```
class Profesionales(models.Model):
"""Model definition for Profesionales."""

# TODO: Define fields here
idProfesional= models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
idPersona = models.OneToOneField('Personas',on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

El modelo para **idPersona**

```
class Personas(User):
    """Model definition for Personas."""
    idPersona = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = False, null = False)
    Apaterno = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = False, null = False)
    Amaterno = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = False, null = False)
    fNacimiento = models.DateField(auto_now = False, blank = False, null = False)
```

El modelo **profesionprofesional**

```
class ProfesionProfesional(models.Model):
idProfesionProfesional = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
idProfesion = models.ForeignKey('Profesiones', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
idProfesional =  models.ForeignKey('Profesionales', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Descripcion = models.TextField(blank = False, null = False)
valorReferencia = models.FloatField(blank= True,null= False, default = 0)
```

**Serializador**

```
class FullProfesionProfesionalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
idProfesion = FullProfesionesSerializer(read_only=False)
idProfesional = FullProfesionalesSerializer(read_only=False)
class Meta:
    model = ProfesionProfesional
    fields = '__all__'
```

**Vista**

```
class ProfesionalesCategoriaSubcategoriaViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = ProfesionProfesional.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FullProfesionProfesionalSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(idCategoria = self.kwargs['cat_pk'], idSubcategoria = self.kwargs['sub_pk'])
```

Esto genera este error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'idCategoria' into field`

Comment: Puedes incluir más código? por favor al menos agrega los modelos. ¿Que estas mostrando en ese diccionario que colocaste? Agrega además los filtros que has intentado utilizar. Está difícil ayudarte con la (poca) información que das.

Comment: @Vichoko Hola, ya te añadí lo que solicitabas ojalá me puedas ayudar, estoy mostrando una lista de profesionales en lo que puse primero y lo que quiero es filtrarlos de acuerdo a la categoría y subcategoría solicitada.

Comment: En la vista haces un filter sobre el queryset de ProfesionProfesional, este modelo no está listado entre los modelos que están en tu pregunta. Es clave poder verlo para entender su estructura y poder ayudarte con la consulta de filtro que quieres hacer.

Comment: Es un sencillamente una relación entre el modelo de Profesión y Profesional, pero tienes campos adicionales...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer consultas sobre campos anidados dentro de otro modelo, como en tu caso que los campos que deseas filtrar están en una relación *Many-to-one*, es decir dentro de un modelo referenciado por medio de un campo `ForeignKey`. Para ver todos los detalles de este tipo de relaciones te invito a leer su [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships), ahi se especifican diversos ejemplos entre los cuales se incluyen parecidos a tu caso de uso.

Yendo al grano del problema:

> Con doble guíon bajo se puede referenciar campos de una referencia por `ForeignKey`.

Por lo que el codigo debería quedar algo así:

```
class ProfesionalesCategoriaSubcategoriaViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = ProfesionProfesional.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FullProfesionProfesionalSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(idProfesion__idCategoria = self.kwargs['cat_pk'], idProfesion__idSubcategoria = self.kwargs['sub_pk'])
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!... Funciona a la perfección.